# Cut transparent parts image

Tags: c#, image-processing, crop

The updated image:[image]

thanks you very much man but i wanted to do somthing little different, to cut each rectangle here as a sperate image.Lets try first to find the blue block Bounds. Sounds hard but its actually simple.

look when i have done so far:

```
  private unsafe Bitmap CodeImage(Bitmap bmp)
    {

        Bitmap bmpRes = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);


        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;


        int stride = bmData.Stride;


        int nWidth = bmp.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp.Height;
        int minX = 10000 ;
        int maxX = -10000;
        int minY = 10000;
        var maxY = -10000;

        bool found = false;
        for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
            p += y * stride;


            for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
            {




                if (p[3]!=0)  //Check if pixel is transpert;
                {


                    found = true;
                  if (x < minX)
                      minX = x;
                  if (y < minY)
                      minY = y;
                   if (x > maxX)
                      maxX = x;
                  if (y > maxY)
                      maxY = y;

                }

                else
                {
                    if (found)
                    {


                        Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(minX, minY, maxX - minX,  maxY-minY);


                        return bmp.Clone(temp, bmp.PixelFormat);
                    }
                }



                p += 4;


            }
        }


        return null;

    }
```

you actually was write and i should calculate the width like this :
`int width = maxX - minX;` and it actually works.. but the height is 0....

try this out man its outputing almost correct rectangle with these bounds:
(200,800,400, and **0** on the height).
i just used parts of your code in my algorithm and yea you were right but now there is a little problem with the height i' would very appreciate if you will have a look

Comment: The start (upper left corner of a rect) is the Min(x,y) of any non-transparent pixel. The end (lower right corner of the rect) is the Max(x,y) of any non-transparent pixel. Should be easy from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write this in pseudo-ish-code since you should be able then to apply it to any type of image or language...

```
var minX = 10000
var maxX = -10000
var minY = 10000
var maxY = -10000

for (var y = 0 to height)
{
    for (var x = 0 to width)
    {
        if (pixel(x,y).Color != transparent)
        {
            if (x < minX) minX = x
            if (y < minY) minY = y
            if (x > maxX) maxX = x
            if (y > maxY) maxY = y
        }
    }
}

var cropRectangle = (minX, minY, maxX, maxY)
```

You can now use standard functions on the bitmap to get that area, which should be the area bounded by the non-transparent pixels.

Comment: first of all a huge thanks for you help! i appreciate it! i tried your suggestion and you can see the updated code on the quesition itself but maybe there's little somthing wrong in the code logic? because im getting still same image when im trying to clone from the changed rectangle...may you have a look again? thanks! @Ron Beyer

Comment: Pixels aren't necessarily transparent only if all 4 RGBA values are 0, you should only be checking the "a" channel for 0. Also, you are always checking the same pixel (never adding to the pointer where `p` is set, so you are only checking the first 4 elements of that array. You need to offset the 0,1,2,3 by the X value to get the current pixel.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint for X and Y at the first known pixel to see if you are checking for the right value? Maybe A is 1 instead of 0?

Comment: used this ` MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString());` printed 0,0. @RonBeyer

Comment: That prints the X and Y, but if you know (from using paint or whatever) that the top corner of the rectangle is 1500,1200, set a breakpoint for the loop with a condition of X == 1500 && Y == 1200 and then look at the value of p[3].

Comment: And if you step back one pixel to the one just before the transparent pixel?

Comment: its  0 on pixel before @RonBeyer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86800/discussion-between-slashy-and-ron-beyer).

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't chat, but here, this worked for me using your test image: http://pastebin.com/kvki084f You may have to move the `bmp.UnlockBits` call before the return though, thats the only problem I had and didn't fix it before I put it up.

Comment: allright very thanks man! just one last thing  there is a problem with the height.. seems like `maxY-minY` always results as 0... can you come for a chat only for 2 mins? @Ron Beyer

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't chat. I tried this with the image you provided and get a height that is not zero, and an image that returns just the red square... Have you debugged? Did you copy/paste my code?

Comment: yes i just checked it. i updated the question loook it pleasee @Ron Beyer

Comment: no no... its actually a little better implemention of the code... i just use `else` statment when its stopped finding non transpert pixels then i understand the block is over. have  a little look @Ron Beyer it almost works but only the height...

Comment: Look, I apologize for this but I've put a lot more time into this than I normally would. Originally it was just trim the image to exclude the non-transparent areas now you want to pick out individual blocks. I would start a new question saying thats what you want to do, I really can't put more time into this than I already have given you've changed the parameters of the question significantly from its original intent.

Comment: allright i understand! thank you very much! you're awesome man @Ron Beyer